# Django ORM: SUM of grouped MAX

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I am trying to translate this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT user_id, SUM(max_score) 
FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score
      FROM submissions 
      GROUP BY exercise_id, user_id) AS subquery 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

where the table `submissions` has the columns `user_id`, `exercise_id` and `score`.

Translating the inner subquery results in:

```py
        subquery = (
            Submission.objects
            .values("exercise", "user")
            .annotate(max_score=Max("score"))
            .values("user", "max_score")
        )
```

with a queryset like this:

```py
<QuerySet [{'user': 1, 'max_score': 27}, 
           {'user': 2, 'max_score': 50}, 
           {'user': 1, 'max_score': 16}, 
           {'user': 3, 'max_score': 14}, 
           {'user': 1, 'max_score': 14}, 
           ...]>
```

However, when I try to sum it up by user using `subquery.annotate(total_score=Sum("max_score"))` I get:

> FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('max_score'): 'max_score' is an aggregate

How could I implement this in Django ORM instead of an inefficient solution like this:

```py
        scores = defaultdict(int)
        for row in subquery:
            scores[row['user']] += row['max_score']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = subquery.aggregate(total_score=Sum("max_score"))
```

To access the value in result:

```py
result['total_score']
```

`annotate` returns rows with a special attribute set on each row which you specify in the method argument, but it still returns rows (QuerySet). The `aggregate` method returns a result of an aggregation - one value.

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Hi thanks but I don't want a single result (sum of all max_score's) but a sum per user (see the GROUP BY in the SQL statement).